# Driving high current through an LED using PWM

Tags: transistors, led, pwm

We are trying to use an LED as a high frequency light source, using PWM implemented through an Arduino. We use an NPN transistor to boost the voltage drop (and current flow) through the LED, per the figure below. The TTL pulse is supplied at Vin and an external voltage (5V) is applied at Vcc. Our application requires that the LED is on for a very short duration (4 microseconds).

We find that when we set the PWM for such short pulse durations, there is a very low voltage drop across the LED (~1V) and hence not much light from the LED. Is this to be expected? And is there any way to boost the light output?

Vin is a TTL pulse, Vcc is 5V DC, Rb is 500 ohms, Rc is 15 ohms

LED is [Broadcom / Avago HLMP-CM1A-560DD](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/broadcom-limited/HLMP-CM1A-560DD/6677169)

Transistor is [2N3904](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/2N3904-82270.pdf)

[image: LED circuit]

Comment: real TTL needs a pull R , maybe you should use a PNP or CMOS

Comment: please provide  p/n of TTL pulse  IC?  You don't have enough current 74LS  Voh = 2.4 to 3.4V typ @ 400uA min

Comment: It is a 3.3 LV TTL output with 0-0.4 V on low and 2.4-3.465 V on the high side.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't quite understand (not an EE major!). I need a much higher current from TTL?

Comment: Also the voltage drop (and LED brightness) are excellent when using a 100% duty cycle PWM. The problem is both drop as we reduce PWM duty cycle down to the 4mu.s we need for the very short LED pulse.

Comment: Please give us the part number of the pulse-generation ic. Tony and I are wondering whether it can even theoretically drive the transistor fast enough.

Comment: The problem with LSTTL outputs is that they have weak Voh drive - drive which you need to hit that transistor base hard to achieve the current rise-time you're looking for. You could try using a FET instead, like a BSS138.

Comment: Thanks. We are generating the TTL pulse using a National Instruments myRIO module. https://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/376047c.pdf

Comment: I skimmed your datasheet it find its max diode forward current If only 30mA. I think you can try 1W LED with 350mA max, or 3W LED with 750mA max. Let me see if I can get you some references.

Comment: Using a power LED as TLfong suggests would be wise.  Even if the LED survives being overpowered, you get depreciating returns in brightness as you overdrive it, so if brightness matters you're better off starting with a larger LED.  Are you measuring voltage with an oscilloscope?  You can get a cheap one for $20 if you need to, but a voltmeter will only tell you the average voltage.  Also, just personal experience, but I found it easier to get sharp turn on and off with a mosfet and mosfet driver rather than a transistor.

Comment: Your brightness is determined by duty cycle, not pulse duration.  If your current circuit is in fact switching fast enough, but you only run the LED at 1% duty cycle, you should expect low brightness.  If you're running 4uS pulses at a 50% duty cycle and you're getting less than half brightness, that would indicate you're not switching fast enough.

Comment: Check that your Rb is 500 and not 500k which might give you Vled =1V at very low current !

Comment: I have experience driving IR LED's at 1A with low duty cycle. It works fine as far as LED reliability goes. But it is a challenge to get such high current through an LED and to turn it on and off crisply. Without confirming via oscilloscope what the Vf waveform looks like I would not draw any conclusions about your success or failure at 4uA. If you are probing with a voltmeter, then you are not getting the full picture. Everything may be working as you want. Or maybe not.

Comment: I suspect it's actually working as you want and just dim due to low duty cycle. 4 us is not that fast for a single LED and transistor. Get a scope and measure.

Answer (score 2):

4 microseconds is not a lot of time, so the parasitic inductance and capacitance could be a problem.

It is impossible to tell from the current schematics, but if you have an oscilloscope, you need to:

- Measure the voltage on the transistor's base. What is the rise time there? If it is too long, then maybe your IC's output is not powerful enough, or you have a parasitic capacitance in that circuit.
- Measure the voltage on the transistor's collector. It should have a fast rise as well. If it does not, then you have too much capacitance on the input.
- You can also measure the current on Rc to see if there is a problem with parasitic inductance -- but this is pretty unlikely unless your LED is on the very long wire.

Comment: I would totally not trust that the LED is on for 4us unless I saw the collector dipping low for 4us on the scope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more than likely that the NPN transistor does not act like an ideal switch at high frequencies. It likely needs more than 4us to turn on. It is a known fact that NPN switches are generally much slower than MOSFETs. So you have three options:

1. Increase the on time to ensure the NPN turns on.
2. Use a logic level MOSFET (one that can turn on with just 3.3-5V applied to the gate)
3. Use a baker-clamp circuit, see below, to speed up the switching time of the NPN. You can read more about a baker-clamp [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_clamp).

[image]